# Normalization or Modifying data to specific range which is better?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, vector

I have column vector of 180 elements,for applying this as feature to any pattern recognition algorithm I read as we need to do the normalization of the vector. 
max and min values of the vector are 19.04881 and 8.4015 respectively.
First I have used matlab inbuilt function `normc(vector)` and when I checked the values the max and min, i obtained as 0.0693 and 0.0306 respectively. 
Secondly, I normalized the values to range 0 and 1 by using `normalised_vector = (vector-min(vector))./max(vector)` where I have obtained max and min values as 0.5589 and 0 respectively.

when used description of normc function in matlab it is describing as normalization of the given matrices. But so other examples gave me the second method. 
Out of these two ways, the normalized values are completely different, and when applied my algorithm using these values the results are completely different.
Both of these method dont work when I have negative values in it.

Which way of data normalization is correct way ? or my understanding is wrong ?
or I am missing some concept here ?
am i comparing to two irrelevant methods ? 
Please suggest !

Comment: The "correct" way depends on what purpose you have for normalizing your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @excaza mentioned normalization can have different meaning regarding your application. 
If by normalization you mean **re-scaling** or **mapping**, when you normalize to range `[0 1]` then the minimum value and the maximum value will be re-scaled to `0` and `1` respectively. So the second method you mentioned is actually mapping from a range to another, using the minimum and maximum values and linear scaling.

To map a vector in range `[a b]` to range `[0 1]` you can follow this formula:

```
v2 = (v1 – a) / (b-a);
```

for instance in MATLAB:

```
V = 10*rand(10,1)+2;
Vscaled = (V-min(V))/(max(V)-min(V))
```

In general, to map from range `[a b]` to range `[c d]` use the following formula:

```
v2 = [  (c+d) + (d-c)* [(2*v1 – (a+b)) / (b-a)]  ] / 2
```

You can also [write a function](https://machinelearning1.wordpress.com/2014/07/13/linear-vector-mapping-scaling-matlab/) for this kind of scaling.

Comment: Thank you NKN, for the tip. I am rescaling only. I have used 'mat2gray(vector)' to rescale my values. The link you provided was useful when I wanted to rescale in different ranges.

Comment: You appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site in your post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. Please see: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [the help center on self-promotion](/help/promotion). Disclosure must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. When it's your own *personal* content, it can just be something like "on my site…", "on my blog…", etc. Please [edit] your post to include disclosure of affiliation.